# How to disallow usage of an LDAP root account

Tags: authentication, pam, ldap

I am responsible for a couple of servers at my university. All of these machines are configured to talk to the LDAP server of my departement to allow centralised user logins. On this LDAP server there is a user named `root`:

```
# getent passwd | grep root
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
root:x:0:0:Netbios Domain Administrator:/home/root:/bin/false
```

Recently, I ran into issues with the `root` account on one of the servers I am responsible for: My SSH connection attempt was successfully authenticated against the local `root` user, but the home directory was taken from the LDAP as `/home/root`. In addition I found out that one can authenticate as root with the LDAP's `root` credentials on any server, i.e., if authentication against the local `root` fails, the LDAP `root` is tried and, given the password is correct, the user is logged in as superuser.

I believe this is not very secure and the ambiguity of the two `root` accounts should be removed. However, according to our IT department, the LDAP `root` is necessary.

How can I filter out the `root` account from LDAP to disallow authentication with it? I am using `pam_ldap.so` and also some ldap directives in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways, here are a couple of easy ones:

- in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` change `PermitRootLogin` to no (this is usually a good idea, then rely on `su`/`sudo` for administration). This affects SSH only of course.
- in the various PAM configuration files use the `pam_listfile` module to explicitly allow or deny certain accounts (needs to be done for each service)
- in the various PAM configuration files configure the `pam_ldap` module `pam_min_uid` to 1 (or higher) so that root cannot log in (needs to be done for each service)
- amend the PAM LDAP search filter (`pam_filter`) to either exclude users (e.g. `pam_filter (uidNumber>=1)`, or you may be able to amend the base/scope

Either of the last two might be the best fit for you. You may also need to make some adjustments to the local PAM configuration so that a local root account via `pam_unix`  can succeed if `pam_ldap` fails it (e.g. ordering and required/requisite/sufficient).

Comment: Hi, thank you for pointing out different ways. The first is not really sufficient, because `su root` is affected with the same problem. But I'll try the other ones.

Comment: The only thing I'd like to add is in `/etc/lapd.conf` you can filter out through `nss_initgroups_ignoreusers` section

Comment: Thank you. A 6th option is to append the filder mentioned by mr.spuratic to the `nss_base_passwd` and `nss_base_shadow` lines in `/etc/ldap/ldap.conf` and `/etc/libnss-ldap.conf`.